# VueJS and Vuex, Dynamic import and dynamic component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm new in VueJS and Vuex, so I have problem with dynamically import component.

The problem is that when I try to access to the this.$store, that will return undefined.

This is my file structure:

`components
- books.vue
- modals
-- bookOne.vue
-- bookTwo.vue
...
-- bookTen.vue`

in books.vue I'm using the  tag where I'm loading the components from modal folder.
The modal works, the component is loaded, but I'm not able to use this.$store into the modals.

books.vue

```
<modal name="example">
  <div class="basic-modal">
    <h1 class="title">Modal Title</h1>
    <component :is="this.modalComponent"></component>
    <button class="button" type="button" @click="close">Close Modal</button>
  </div>
</modal>
```

modals/bookOne.vue

```
created () {
  console.log('deb', this.$store)
  // this.$store returns undefined
},
computed: {
  testing() {
    console.log('testing', this.$store)
    // this.$store is undefined
  }
},
```

I'm using this module for the modals:
https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-modal

So, what could be the problem ? Maybe the live cycle of the application because the modals are imported dynamically after initialization the webpack or ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `this.$store` defined in `books.vue`? Are you supplying a store when you instantiate vue?

Comment: @sklingler93 Yes, I have imported store into Vue instance and also I'm using getters into books.vue (this.$store.getters.allBooks...)

Comment: Do the `getters` working?

Comment: @kevguy In the parent component the getters works, but in the component that is dynamically loaded getters not works because $store property is missed.

Comment: @Damjan Hahaha I have the *exact* same problem, identical code and everything. Very funny. Did you somehow manage to solve this? I cannot access my vuex actions from my dynamic component :P